# Nginx on Docker Unable to reach site

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have this docker compose file that I added an nginx section to:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  rp:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 8120:80
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/conf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    depends_on:
     - sdr_filestore.api

  sdr_filestore.api:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}sdrfilestoreapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: SDR_Filestore.Api/Dockerfile
    networks: 
    - dev
    ports:
    - 59521:80
```

This is the nginx.conf file:

```
events {

}
http {

    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name localhost;
        server_tokens off;
    }

}
```

When I run docker-compose, it compiles and runs fine. However, when I go to http://localhost:8120, I get this error:

> This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect.

I then tried another method which is to just run the command straight from the Nginx website:

> docker run --name mynginx1 -p 8120:80 -d nginx

This also runs fine and when I go to http://localhost:8120, I get the nginx page. What did I configure wrong in my first docker compose file?

EDIT: After docker run --rm nginx cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't overwrite `nginx.conf` with your volume. Instead do the following:

```
volumes:
- ./nginx/conf/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
```

where `default.conf` is:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name localhost;
        server_tokens off;
    }
```

If you want to see why, check the contents of `nginx.conf` and `default.conf` inside the original image:

```
docker run --rm nginx cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

docker run --rm nginx cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Comment: Do I remove the http tags from the default.conf also?

Comment: yes. they are already in `nginx.conf`.

Comment: I changed the files according to your answer but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: When I inspect nginx within the container, i can see that the port has been set to 0.0.0.0:8120 though.. I tried looking at default.conf and the server settings are there.

Comment: what do you mean "the port has been set to 0.0.0.0:8120"? where do you see that?

Comment: in the inspect section on docker. 80/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:8120

Comment: ok but that;s not inside the container, it is on the host. and it is 0.0.0.0:8120 -> 80/tcp, not the other way around. Also your version of default.conf does not have a location for `/`. try adding one. Look at the last comment in my answer. That is a `default.conf` that works

Comment: Sorry what do you mean default.conf does not have a location for /? Your last comment in the answer is docker run --rm nginx cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf. I have added the default.conf after running the last command in my questions.

Comment: @JianYA I have just tried this: `docker run -d --rm --name nginx -v $(pwd)/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf -p 8120:80 nginx` with your version of `default.conf` and it works (`curl -vI http://localhost:8120`). It only responds 404 because it cannot find `index.html`

Comment: But by default shouldn't there be an index.html? So I should add a location now?

Comment: yes, forget about that. I responded above that it works without.